# ShopWare 6 PlugIn

Tags: shopware

i got 2 cloud based sw6 and one real woodclass low budget planner sw6
but in the cloud based sw6 i havent a plugin installer only showing me migration of sw5
and in my wood low budget class i only have a complete destroyed but working sw6 system

here the link http://shopware.silvervine.eu/public/
my admin also loOoks like its broken http://shopware.silvervine.eu/public/#admin/
think my installation went wrong or maybe i have to change the root structure

please help
SORRY for my english

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption about your wrong folder structure is correct.
Your webserver document root must not be set to the projects root, but to the folder `public` inside your project.

You can relate to the [Shopware 6 Documentation](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/system-guide/installation#setting-up-your-webserver) for configuring your Apache web server.
For nginx you have to google because there is no offical documentation.